# Why does Flex Builder fail to connect the app so often?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

Flex Builder often fails to connect to the app that it's supposed to debug.  After a minute or so it times-out and says that it couldn't connect.  The only way I can get it to stop doing this is by restarting Eclipse.

Very annoying.  Anyone know why this is?

I'm using FB 3.1 and Firefox on Win XP.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This became an issue with Firefox 3, and the general workaround is to start disabling Firefox extensions until it works.  I've found that the AdBlock and IETab extensions interfered with Flex debugging; once those were disabled in Firefox's Add-On Manager, things got better.

See [this bug report](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-13064) on Adobe's website for much more information.

Answer (score -2):

I think it may be because it's full of bugs. I haven't worked with it on windows but on os x it reeks. You have to restart the whole os to get it back to normal sometimes.